# Return list with key value which is not None

Tags: python, list, numpy, dictionary

I have a list like this:

```
[{"value": 19, "datetime": "2021-01-01T00:30:00Z"},
     {"value": None, "datetime": "2021-01-01T00:40:00Z"},
    {"value": None, "datetime": "2021-01-01T00:50:00Z"},
    {"value": None, "datetime": "2021-01-01T00:55:00Z"}]
```

I would like to return the list of which key the 'value' expect None

So the example output should be:

```
[{"value": 19, "datetime": "2021-01-01T00:30:00Z"}]
```

I have tried this:

```
def do_something():
  for li in my_list:
    if li['value']:
        print(li)
```

Comment: A simple list comprehension? `return [element for element in my_list if element['value'] is not None]`

Comment: See: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions for more info.

Answer (score 2):

Just do this:

```
your_list = [
    {"value": 19, "datetime": "2021-01-01T00:30:00Z"},
    {"value": None, "datetime": "2021-01-01T00:40:00Z"},
    {"value": None, "datetime": "2021-01-01T00:50:00Z"},
    {"value": None, "datetime": "2021-01-01T00:55:00Z"},
]

print([item for item in your_list if item["value"] is not None])
```

Output:

```
[{'value': 19, 'datetime': '2021-01-01T00:30:00Z'}]
```